# Winforms bind SelectedItems in listbox

Tags: winforms

Using the standard listbox I would like to bind it to a set of objects and update a bound items collection to include those selected.

So I have something like:

```
    _pContext = new BindingSource();
_pContext.DataSource = _gpContext;
_pContext.DataMember = "ParentEntities";
_AllChildrenListBox.DataSource = _container.ChildEntities;
_AllChildrenListBox.DataBindings.Add("MySelectedItems", _pContext, "ChildEntities", false);
```

_allChildrenListBox is the listbox. I created a new listbox type inheriting from ListBox so I could create an alternative SelectedItems property which would then encapsulate the logic to set/unset the items.

So the question in a nutshell is: In the above, ChildEntities is a collection of "ChildEntity" objects. My list box contains all possible ChildEntity objects and I want the elements in ChildEntities to be selected, and updated when selection changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around this. It's a little ugly at the moment, but works. I can refine it later.

So first bit was the binding itself.

```
_AllChildrenListBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItems2", _pContext, "ChildEntities2", true);
```

The key here seemed to be setting the formatting parameter to true.

Next I needed something in SelectedItems2 that would do my dirty work. This is a mess, but works. Here's the full class:

```
    public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    private IEnumerable<object> _original;

    public IEnumerable<object> SelectedItems2
    {
        get
        {
            return UpdateSet();
        }
        set
        {
            SelectItems(value);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> UpdateSet()
    {
        var listSource = _original as IListSource;
        IList list = null;
        if (listSource != null)
        {
            list = listSource.GetList();
        }
        var iList = _original as IList;
        if (list == null && iList != null)
        {
            list = iList;
        }
        if (list == null)
        {
            return _original;
        }

        foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
        {
            if (!list.Contains(item))
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in _original.ToList())
        {
            if (!SelectedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                list.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        return _original;

    }

    private void SelectItems(IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        _original = items;
        var hashset = new HashSet<object>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            hashset.Add(item);
        }
        for(var i=0;i<Items.Count;i++)
        {
            SetSelected(i, hashset.Contains(Items[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm breaking all the rules and assuming IEnumerable hides a more tasty list based interface, if it does it uses that to changes the underlying set.

Finally, I'm using EF (Entity Framework) and you can't call the setter of a collection property, so my entity currently looks like this: Notice how I'm duplicating all the list change operations which is totally unnecessary, but I did say this was just the first working go.

```
    public partial class ParentEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<object> ChildEntities2
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<object>(ChildEntities);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (var item in ChildEntities.ToList().Where(item => !value.Contains(item)))
            {
                ChildEntities.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                var cItem = item as ChildEntity;
                if (cItem != null)
                {
                    if (!ChildEntities.Contains(item as ChildEntity))
                    {
                        ChildEntities.Add(item as ChildEntity);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this is a real hack, and really just proof of concept. If you know of a cleaner approach I'd be interested.